# Find Average of numbers using a Text File in Java

Tags: java, file, average, filereader

```
package txtfileaverage;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Frazer
 */
public class Txtfile {

    public static void main(String args[])  throws IOException
     {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("input.txt")); 

        int numTimes = file.nextInt();
        file.nextLine();

            for(int i = 0; i < numTimes; i++);
            {   
                int sum = 0;
                int count = 0;
              Scanner split = new Scanner(file.nextLine());
              while(split.hasNextInt())
                //for (int a = 0; a < 4 ; a++)
                {
        sum += split.nextInt();
        count++;
                }    
        System.out.println("the average is = " + ((double)sum / count));

            }
                }

}
```

Text File:

```
4

100 100 100 100

100 100 50  50

100 90  80  70

60  50  40  30
```

the above is the text file i am trying to read from, the output that is displayed is

"the average is 100" but it either only looks at one number or 1 line, any tips on how to get it to read the other lines? i have had a look at some tutorial and after comparing the code i'm struggling to find out why it's only finding the average of 1 number or 1 line rather than the whole row, each with another statement.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 [Collectors.averagingInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), it is as simple as:

```
 Arrays.stream(Files.lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(
                    "input.txt").toURI())).reduce((a, b) -> a + " " + b)
.map(e -> e.split(" ")).get()).filter(e -> e.matches("\\d+"))
.map(Integer::new)
.collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::intValue));
```

**Usage:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FindAverage {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            URISyntaxException {

        Double average = Arrays
                .stream(Files
                        .lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(
                                "input.txt").toURI()))
                        .reduce((a, b) -> a + " " + b).map(e -> e.split(" "))
                        .get()).filter(e -> e.matches("\\d+"))
                .map(Integer::new)
                .collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::intValue));

        System.out.println("Average = " + average);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code here should work. What I am doing here is going through the file line by line with the while loop. With each line, I am splitting the parts by your specified delimiter, space. Then, I loop through the elements, `trim()` it which removes excess spaces, grab the integer, and add it to sum. For each of the integers I take, I add to count. At the very end it's the same as yours.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));

        String line = null;
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = file.nextLine()) != null) {
            String[] vals = line.split(" ");
            for(int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
                sum += Integer.valueOf(vals[i].trim());
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the average is = " + ((double) sum / count));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to calculate the average from a text file. Just write an if statement within the while loop.

[See Code Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMG4A.png)

Comment: Please add the code here and don't provide a link to a code screenshot.